# Pointer arithmetic output issues

Tags: c, gcc

Here are we use typecasting from pointer to integer, but output of arithmetic operation are different from expected answer, Why?

Source Code :

```
int main(){
    int *p,*q;
    p = 1000;
    q = 2000;
    printf("%d",q-p);
return 0;
}
```

Output: **250**

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the base type. In your case in units of `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Also note that doing arithmetic on two unrelated pointers is highly discouraged, and IIRC even [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Formally, the behaviour is undefined `"%d"` is the wrong specifier and you're doing pointer arithmetic on two locations that are not part of the same array.

Comment: To printf the difference of pointers you want to use [`t` length modifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7).

Comment: Lastly, the result of pointer arithmetic is a value of the type [`ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t), which must be printed using the `t` length modifier. As in `"%td"`. See e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for details about format specifiers.

Comment: No @Karsten Koop I think its different question because of there are output are different after arithmetic operation.

Comment: Yes @alk i want

Comment: "*typecasting from pointer to integer*" this is *not* a cast, but an "**implicit** conversion".

Comment: Yes @alk, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same reason due to which p++ will give you 1004. Since `sizeof(int)` on your machine is 4, hence each operation is shown wrt `sizeof(int)`, even the difference i.e. 1000/4.